# How exactly is a Decimal object encoded in python?

Tags: python, decimal

I'm currently writing code using `decimal.Decimal` in python (v3.8.5).

I was wondering if anyone knows how the Decimal object is actually encoded.

I can't understand why the memory size is the same even if I change `getcontext().prec`, which is equal to change coefficients and exponent in decimal floating-points, as follows

```
from decimal import *
from sys import getsizeof

## coefficient bits = 3
getcontext().prec = 3

temp = Decimal('1')/Decimal('3')

print(temp.as_tuple()) >>> DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(3, 3, 3), exponent=-3)
print(getsizeof(temp)) >>> 104

## coefficient bits = 30
getcontext().prec = 30

temp = Decimal('1')/Decimal('3')

print(temp.as_tuple()) >>> DecimalTuple(sign=0, digits=(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), exponent=-30)
print(getsizeof(temp)) >>> 104
```

In order to understand the above behavior, I read the source code of Decimal class and the attached document.

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_pydecimal.py
- http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decarith.html
- http://speleotrove.com/decimal/decbits.pdf

According to the document, Python's Decimal object is implemented based on IEEE 754-2008, and the decimal digits of coefficient continuation are converted into binary digits using DPD (Densely packed decimal) encoding.

Therefore, according to the DPD algorithm, we can calculate the number of bits when the decimal digits of the coefficient continuation are encoded into binary digits.

And since the sign, exponent continuation, and combination field are simply expressed in binary, the number of bits when encoded can be easily calculated.

So, we can calculate the number of bits when Decimal obejcet is encoded by the following formula.
bits = (sign) + (exp) + (comb) + (compressed coeff)

Here, sign and combination are fixed at 1bit and 5bits, respectively (according to the definition of IEEE 754-2008. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_floating_point).

So, I wrote the above code to check the list of {sign, exponent, coefficient} using `as_tuple()` of the Decimal object, and calculate the actual number of bits in memory.

However, as mentioned above, the memory size of the Decimal object did not change at all, even though the number of digits in the coefficient should have changed.
(I understand that a Decimal object is not only a decimal encoding but also a list and other objects.)

The following two questions arise.

(1) Am I wrong in my understanding of the encoding algorithm of the Decimal object in python?
(Does python3.8.5 use a more efficient encoding algorithm than IEEE 754-2008?)

(2) Assuming that my understanding of the algorithm is correct, why does the memory size of the Decimal object remain the same even though the coefficient has been changed?
(According to the definition of IEEE754-2008, when coefficient continuation is changed, exponent continuation is also changed, and total bits should be changed.)

I myself am a student who usually studies in the field of mechanical engineering, and I am a complete beginner in informatics.
If there is any part of my original understanding that is wrong or if there is any strange logical development, please let me know.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

Since `Decimal` is a Python class with references to several other objects (EDIT: see below), you just get the total size of the references, which is constant — not including the referred values, which are not.

```
getcontext().prec = 3
temp = Decimal(3) / Decimal(1)
print(sys.getsizeof(temp))
print(sys.getsizeof(temp._int))

getcontext().prec = 300
temp = Decimal(3) / Decimal(1)
print(sys.getsizeof(temp))         # same
print(sys.getsizeof(temp._int))    # not same
```

(Note that `_int` slot I used in the example is an internal implementation detail of CPython's `Decimal`, as hinted by the leading underscore; this code is not guaranteed to work in other Python implementations, or even in other versions.)

---

**EDIT:** Oops, my first answer was on an old Python, where `Decimal` is implemented in Python. The version you asked about has it [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c).

The C version actually stores everything inside the object itself, but your difference in precision was not sufficient to detect the difference (as memory is allocated in discrete chunks). Try it with `getcontext().prec = 300` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response that ```sys.getsizeof()``` only gets the total size of the references.

I misunderstood that it was the memory size when encoded.

Also, thanks for the tip on how to get inside CPython's ```Decimal```!

What is the version of decimal in the your implementation?
(In my environment, it was v1.7.0)

As you mentioned, I got an error message;
```
AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute '_int'
```

Thank you again for your kind!

Comment: Actually, it seems I was testing on a very different Python, one where `Decimal` was implemented in Python rather than in C. I will update my answer.

Comment: Just to clarify – `._int` would work if your interpreter used the class you linked. :)

Comment: I got confirmation that they have different sizes!

This is the first time I've posted a question on stackoverflow and I'm very glad to get the information I'm looking for.

I am filled with gratitude for you.
Thank you again and again for your kindness !!!

Comment: @TMo And according to the upvotes it was a good question.